# calculating truncated infinite AR weights in practice for Arima model

Tags: arima, stationarity, box-jenkins

I am trying to figure out how to form the truncated infinite AR weights for a general time series process.

$(1 - \phi_1 B - \phi_2 B^2 - ... - \phi_p B^p)(1 - B)z_t = (1-\theta_1 B - ... - \theta_q B^q)a_t$

Where $\phi \text{ and } \theta$ are some constants, $z_t$ is a series of measurements, $a_t$ is noise, and $B$ is the backshift operator $B * z_t = z_{t-1}$.

Let

$\phi(B) = (1 - \phi_1 B - \phi_2 B^2 - ... - \phi_p B^p)\\
\theta(B) = (1-\theta_1 B - ... - \theta_q B^q)\\
\rho(B) = \phi(B) * (1-B)$

Then this model can also be represented as :
$\rho(B)z_t = \theta(B)a_t$

It is known that these models, if stationary, can be represented by an infinite AR series: 
$$\Psi(B) = \frac{\theta(B)}{\rho(B)} = \frac{1-\theta B}{(1-\phi B)(1-B)} = \sum_0^\infty \psi_iB^i$$

But, $\Psi(B)$ does not converge if the difference operator $(1-B)$ is included in $\rho(B)$, and according to "Time Series Analysis, Forecasting and Control"(Box, Jenkins), this series is only valid if we use the "truncated form" of the model.

The truncated form consists of a sum of a homogeneous and complementary solution with respect to some time point $k$: 
$$
z_t = C_k(t-k) + I_k(t-k)\\
\rho(B)C_k(t-k)=0\\
\rho(B)I_k(t-k) = (1-\theta B)a_t\\
$$

Here, $C_k$ is the homogeneous solution, and $I_k$ is the complementary solution, where $I_k(t-k) = 0$ when $t\leq k$, and $k$ represents a value where the series is truncated, such as the first data point in some time series.

1. *How would one calculate the complementary function in practice?*

The book gives the formula 
$$
I_k(t-k) = a_t + \psi_1 a_{t-1} + ... + \psi_{t-(k+1)} a_{k+1}\\
I_k(s-k) = 0 \text{ if } s \leq k
$$

I was thinking I should write out the equation:
$$\rho(B)I_k(t-k) = \theta(B)a_{t-k} = (1-\theta_1 B - \theta_2 B^2 - ... - \theta_q B^q) a_{t-k}$$
Then, possibly calculate $I_k(t-k)$ for every data point with $t \geq k$, equate coefficients of the left and right hand side, and solve using least squares if I have more data points than unknowns?

2. *How do I calculate the homogeneous solution in practice?*

The book gives the formula

$$C_k(t-k) = G_0^{t-k}\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}A_j(t-k)^j + \sum_{j=1}^p D_j G_j^{t-k}\\
\text{where } \rho(B) = (1-G_1)(1-G_2)...(1-G_p)(1-G_0)^d$$

Here, $\rho(B)$ has been factored so that you can see it's roots $(G_i)$. This is a general formula given for a case when one factor of $\rho(B)$ repeats $d$ times

In this case, should I use a root solving algorithm to find the roots of $\rho(B)$? If so, would I then form a system of equations with 1 equation for each time $t$, and solve that system for the $A_j$ and $D_j$, probably using least squares since more equations than unknowns (1 for each data point)?

Comment: "...infinite AR" should be infinite MA. Your "general formula" for the homogeneous solution is not really general---each root can have a different multiplicity.

Comment: Least squares does not enter anywhere into the consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...infinite AR weights..." should be infinite MA weights.

Any MA series $z_t = \sum_{i = 0} \psi_i a_{t - i}$, where $\sum |\psi_i| < \infty$, starting at initial time $k$ can be expressed in "truncated-form" 
$$
z_t = \sum_{i = 0}^{t- (k + 1)} \psi_i a_{t - i} \,+ \, E[z_t | z_k, z_{k-1}, z_{k-2}, \cdots],
$$
for $t \geq k$.

For example, take the MA representation of an AR$(1)$ series 
$z_t = \sum_{i = 0} \phi^i a_{t - i}$. The truncated form is
$$
z_t = \sum_{i = 0}^{t-(k+1)} \phi^i a_{t - i} + \underbrace{ \phi^{t-k} z_k }_\text{$E[z_t|z_k, z_{k-1}, \cdots]$}, \;\; t \geq k.
$$

What you are asking for is the ARIMA variation of this. In your notation, 
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{t- (k + 1)} \psi_i a_{t - i} = I_k(t-k),\, E[z_t | z_k, z_{k-1}, z_{k-2}, \cdots] = C_k(t-k).
$$

In the stationary $I(0)$ case, both the MA$(\infty)$ and truncated representation make sense. In the non-stationary $I(1)$ case, the MA$(\infty)$ representation does not make sense; only the truncated form does.

For example, a unit root, i.e. ARIMA(0,1,0), process can be written in truncated form
$$
z_t = \sum_{i = 0}^{t-(k+1)} a_{t - i} + z_k, \; t \geq k
$$ but
$z_t = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} a_{t - i}$ does not make sense.

**General Procedure**

Let $k \geq 0$ be given.
To compute the truncated-form of an ARIMA$(p, 1, q)$ series
$$
(1 - \phi_1 B - \phi_2 B^2 - ... - \phi_p B^p)(1 - B)z_t = (1-\theta_1 B - ... - \theta_q B^q)a_t, \;\; t \geq k,
$$
starting at $k$, do the following.

***Step 1*** *Compute $\psi_i, i = 0, 1, \cdots, t - k -1$.*

Since this is exactly the same as the ARMA case, I'll merge the $(1-B)$ factor of the AR polynomial and write
$$
(1 - \phi_1 B - \phi_2 B^2 - ... - \phi_p B^p)(1 - B) = 1 - \varphi_1 B - \varphi_2 B^2 - ... - \varphi_{p+1} B^{p+1} = \Phi(B).
$$

The weights $\{\psi_i\}_{i \geq 0}$ are solutions to the difference equations

\begin{align*}
\psi_0 &= 1 \\
\psi_1 - \varphi_1 \psi_0 &= \theta_1 \\
\psi_2 - \varphi_1 \psi_1 - \varphi_2 \psi_0 &= \theta_2 \\
\vdots \\
\psi_{p} - \varphi_1 \psi_{p-2} - \cdots \varphi_{p} \psi_0 &= \theta_p, \\
\Phi(B)\psi_i &= 0, \;\; \forall i \geq p. \\
\end{align*}

To compute finitely many (in this case, $t-k$ many) $\psi_i$'s, simply solve the first $p+1$ equations for initial value and iterate forward. This gives $I_k(t-k)$.

In general, the system $\Phi(B)\psi_i = 0, \forall i \geq p$ can be solved like any linear homogeneous system of difference equations of degree $p+1$. 
The general solution $\{ \psi_i \}_{i \geq 0}$ is a linear combination of terms corresponding to the roots of the AR polynomial $\Phi$:
$$
G^{-i} P_{m-1} 
$$
where $G$ is a real root of the multiplicity $m$ and $P_{m-1}$ is a polynomial in $i$ of degree $m-1$.
For example, if $\Phi$ have $p+1$ distinct real roots $G_1, \cdots, G_{p+1}$,
the general solution is
$$
H(t) = c_1 G_1^{-t} + \cdots c_{p+1} G_{p+1}^{-t}.
$$ 
You can look up the case of complex roots.
The coefficients $c_1, \cdots, c_{p+1}$ are given by the initial conditions.

***Step 2*** *Derive $E[z_t | z_k, z_{k-1}, z_{k-2}, \cdots]$.*

Follow the standard way to do this for ARIMA models. 
In general, $E[z_t | z_k, z_{k-1}, z_{k-2}, \cdots]$ is a function $f( z_k, z_{k-1}, z_{k-2}, \cdots)$ of $ z_k, z_{k-1}, z_{k-2}, \cdots$. For example, for the series $z_t = \phi z_{t-1} + a_{t}$ (with no restrictions on $\phi$),
$$
E[z_t | z_k, z_{k-1}, z_{k-2}, \cdots] = \phi^{t-k} z_k = f(z_k).
$$

***Step 3*** *Solve for $C_k(t-k)$.*

$C_k(t-k)$ is a solution to $\Phi(B) x_t = 0$ with $x_k = f( z_k, z_{k-1}, z_{k-2}, \cdots)$.
In other words, $C_k(t-k)$ is just the general homogeneous solution $H(t)$ with the
coefficients $c_1, \cdots, c_{p+1}$ determined by $H(k) = f( z_k, z_{k-1}, z_{k-2}, \cdots)$.

Again the AR(1) is an immediate simple example. In this case, $H(t) = c \phi^{-t}$.
So 
$$
H(k) = f( z_k, z_{k-1}, z_{k-2}, \cdots) 
$$ means
$$
c \phi^{-k} = z_k, 
$$
i.e. $c = \phi^k z_k$.